# How can I use gsub to remove specific characters before and after an arbitrary character in string

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I am attempting to use gsub to remove characters from the following string:

```
string <- "function(data, x = !!rlang::sym(\"Time1\"), y = !!rlang::sym(\"YVAR\")), values = c(\"a\", \"b\"))"
```

The new string should return:

```
cat(string)
function(data, x = Time1, y = YVAR, values = c("a", "b"))
```

that is to say, I'd like to remove `!!rlang::sym(\"`, keep `Time1`, and remove the closing quote and parenthesis after Time1 `\")` (and I'd also like to remove this for `YVAR`)

`Time1` and `YVAR` (x and y variable names) are arbitrary and can be named anything in the resulting string, however, the characters `!!rlang::sym(\"` and the closing quote and parenthesis `\")`after the arbitrary string that needs to be kept are constant and will not change.

I understand I can simply use

```
result <- gsub("!!rlang::sym(\"", "", string, fixed = TRUE)
```

then

```
 result <- gsub("\")", "", result, fixed = TRUE)
```

to get part of the way there, however, I'd like to find a more elegant regex solution that can combine both of these gsub and also will of course not remove the closing `"\")"` in `values = c(\"a\", \"b\"))"`

Comment: Use `gsub('!!rlang::sym\\("(.*?)"\\)', "\\1", result)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```r
result <- gsub("!!rlang::sym\\(\"([\\w\\W]*?)\"\\)", "\\1", string, perl=TRUE)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/zhvy3s/1)

**Expanation**

```r
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  !!rlang::sym             '!!rlang::sym'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \(                       '('
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \"                       '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\w\W]*?                 any character of: word characters (a-z,
                             A-Z, 0-9, _), non-word characters (all
                             but a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \)                       ')'
```

See [R proof](https://tio.run/##ZY7NCsIwEITvfYrtnhKJh16LRTz4AqUq4npIayyFNEp@1D59TOlF8DQw3@zM2hidt4PpYbMGvAfT@eFh2E16KeADFeS51dL0ZemmkRE2w6gKQi5g@ofn465OLMGX1EG5lOiSLQkFELYzwswqF7Sf53oXWoa/HUQpzi5Eb6LTdbXlhEQ8XScpkiyvCngqq6umPux51knPlkoe4xc):

```r
string <- "function(data, x = !!rlang::sym(\"Time1\"), y = !!rlang::sym(\"YVAR\")), values = c(\"a\", \"b\"))"
result <- gsub("!!rlang::sym\\(\"([\\w\\W]*?)\"\\)", "\\1", string, perl=TRUE)
cat(result)
```

**Results**: `function(data, x = Time1, y = YVAR), values = c("a", "b"))`

Answer (score 2):

If it's always the literal `!!rlang::sym("`, then this

```r
cat( gsub('!!rlang::sym\\("(\\S+)"\\)', "\\1", string), "\n" )
# function(data, x = Time1, y = YVAR), values = c("a", "b"))
```

If it's a function-call/paren/quote, then it can be generalized a little. I'd think you'd want *some* specificity, since otherwise you'll be parsing out a lot more than you want. I'll assuming that `rlang` is required:

```r
gsub('\\S+rlang\\S+\\("(\\S+)"\\)', "\\1", string)
```

Note that there are two right-parens in your sample `string`, `!!rlang::sym(\"YVAR\"))`, which are thwarting the pattern just a little. If that's real, then ... either look for repeats with `"\\)+` or ... something else.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a single pattern with a capture group which will match any character except `"`, and use group 1 in the replacement.

```
!!rlang::sym\("([^"]+)"\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SAKUHa/1)

```
string <- "function(data, x = !!rlang::sym(\"Time1\"), y = !!rlang::sym(\"YVAR\")), values = c(\"a\", \"b\"))"
cat(gsub('!!rlang::sym\\("([^"]+)"\\)', "\\1", string))
```

Output

```
function(data, x = Time1, y = YVAR), values = c("a", "b"))
```

[R demo](https://ideone.com/CoIoIu)